# Several questions about continuous, derivative and extrema

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, extreme-value-theorem

Those problems come with my proof of question. I already found a better solution for this question, but there exists some confusion in the first proof occur to my head

Original Question

f(x) is derivable on [a, b], and $f^{'}(a)f^{'}(b)<0$. Prove that there exists at least one point $\xi$ that satisfies $f^{'}(\xi)=0$

Here is my proof,

Suppose that f(x) has no local extrema on (a, b).

Thus, f(x) is monotonic on (a, b), /* **Question 1: Is this true**? */

Therefore, $f^{'}(a)f^{'}(b)>0$, /* **Question 2: Is this true**? */

which contradicts the fact that $f^{'}(a)f^{'}(b)<0$.

Then, there exists at least one extremum on (a, b) and that point is $\xi$. Thus, $f^{'}(\xi)=0$.

**Overall, my question is that if a function is derivable on [a, b] and monotonic on (a, b), can we say anything about the left or right hand derivatives at the end point?**

Suppose f(x) is derivable on [a, b] and monotonically decreasing on (a, b).

Can we say that always f(x) < f(a) ($a\le x \le b$) and use the formula,

$\lim {\frac {f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}} = f^{'}(a) < 0$  ( x-> $a^{+}$ ).

Comment: I have concerns about your statement: Suppose that f(x) has no extrema on (a, b). Consider f(x)=x. Then the maximum is f(b) and the minimum is f(a). So the extrema do exist. I think you wanted to say that suppose f'(x) is non-zero for x in (a,b).

Comment: @MathLover, sorry for the unclear statement, English is not my first language. I want to use the fact if f(x) is a derivable function on [a, b] and has a not-endpoint-kind-of-extremum in (a, b) at $\xi$, then $ f^{'}(\xi) = 0 $. Thus, my goal is to prove that there indeed exists a not-endpoint-kind-of-extremum exists in (a, b). And I want to know if those inaccurate statements are correct and how to state it more correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the intermediate value theorem, then the proof is very easy. Just observe that if $f'(a)*f'(b)<0$, at one endpoint the derivative is positive and on the other endpoint it is negative.

Concerning your proof:
If $f$ is differentiable and monotonic, then the derivative $f'$ does not change its sign. If $f$ is also stric monotonic, then also $f' \ne 0$ and thus $f'(a)*f'(b)>0$. Additionally, if  $f$ has no local extremum, then $f$ is stric monotonic.

Now assume, that $f$ is differentable on $[a,b]$ and monotonically decreasing on $(a,b)$. Then 
$$ \lim_{x \searrow a} \frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\le0$$
because $f(x)<f(a)$ if $x>a$ and the limit exists per assumption.

Comment: Klirk, thank you for your explanation. And something I think I should point out that the question didn't say that $f^{'}$ is continuous. Thus, Intermediate  Value Theorem can not be simply used.